# this.cordova.getActivity().addContentView

Tags: android, cordova

I downloaded the new cordova v3.0.0 and now i am trying to make a plugin.

I made everything and the plugin works, I mafe imageview and everything passed ok.

But than when I try to add this imageView my app dies.

Here is my method:

```
    private void playVideo(String url){
        //layoutparams
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(cordova.getActivity());
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Director/11.0/images/vector_bitmap_image.png");
        iv.setImageURI(myUri);

        //Here the code dies...
        this.cordova.getActivity().addContentView(iv, new LayoutParams(50, 50));
    }
```

What can I do? this code doesnt work even with v2.9.0

10x

Comment: When I try:

this.webView.addView(child)

I get the same error. What it can be?

Comment: somebody told me that i must use:

cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread

but still there is a problem